# Setting alias in Dockerfile not working: command not found

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have the following in my Dockerfile:

```sh
...
USER $user

# Set default python version to 3
RUN alias python=python3
RUN alias pip=pip3

WORKDIR /app

# Install local dependencies
RUN pip install --requirement requirements.txt --user
```

When building the image, I get the following:

```sh
 Step 13/22 : RUN alias pip=pip3
 ---> Running in dc48c9c84c88
Removing intermediate container dc48c9c84c88
 ---> 6c7757ea2724
Step 14/22 : RUN pip install --requirement requirements.txt --user
 ---> Running in b829d6875998
/bin/sh: pip: command not found
```

Why is `pip` not recognized if I set an alias right on top of it?

Ps: I do not want to use `.bashrc` for loading aliases.

Comment: Why alias in the first place? Are you sure that `pip3` points to the python install in that particular image?

Comment: You are looking for this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: How are you installing python in this image?

Comment: @paltaa not quite, docker has no concept of sudo, and the real issue is the use of the `alias` command being run in a different shell during the image construction

Comment: @C.Nivs He wants to set the default for the python interpreter, the alias is just one way of trying to do so

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the alias only exists for that intermediate layer in the image. Try the following:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3-pip -y

RUN alias python=python3
```

Testing here:

```
❰mm92400❙~/sample❱✔≻ docker build . -t testimage
...
Successfully tagged testimage:latest

❰mm92400❙~/sample❱✔≻ docker run -it testimage bash
root@78e4f3400ef4:/# python
bash: python: command not found
root@78e4f3400ef4:/#
```

This is because a new bash session is started for each layer, so the alias will be lost in the following layers.

To keep a stable alias, you can use a symlink as python does in their [official image](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/Dockerfile-debian.template#L95):

```py
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3-pip -y 

# as a quick note, for a proper install of python, you would
# use a python base image or follow a more official install of python,
# changing this to RUN cd /usr/local/bin 
# this just replicates your issue quickly 
RUN cd "$(dirname $(which python3))" \
    && ln -s idle3 idle \
    && ln -s pydoc3 pydoc \
    && ln -s python3 python \ # this will properly alias your python
    && ln -s python3-config python-config

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Note the use of the `python3-pip` package to bundle pip. When calling `pip`, it's best to use the `python -m pip` syntax, as it ensures that the pip you are calling is the one tied to your installation of python:

```sh
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: `cd "$(dirname $(which python3))"` - The proper directory for administrator executables would be `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @KamilCuk that's what I thought, but apt installing into a base ubuntu image places it in `/usr/bin/`, so I felt this was a bit more portable

Comment: The best practice would be to follow a proper install of python, anyways, either by using a python base image, or manually installing python. This was just a quick way to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that by setting aliases in the `/root/.bashrc` file.

> I have followed [this example](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/) to do get an idea on how to do that

PS I am using that in a `jenkins/jenkins:lts` container so as I looked around and as @C.Nivs said:

**The problem is that the alias only exists for that intermediate layer in the image**

So in order to do that I had to find a way to add the following commands:

```sh
ENV FLAG='--kubeconfig /root/.kube/config'
RUN echo "alias helm='helm $FLAG'" >>/root/.bashrc
CMD /bin/bash -c "source /root/.bashrc" && /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
```

for the `CMD` part you have to check the image you are using so you wouldn't interrupt its normal behaviour.